# Why Google Books show different pages from different locations?

Tags: google-books

I have been told that when opening Google Books from different locations (countries) and using different browsers, it displays different pages from the same book. Can anybody explain me why is this?

Comment: I do wonder how truly random this is. I tried connecting from thee different IPs (different ISPs even) but from the same country and I get exactly the same subset of pages blocked. Not logging in to google from any of these machines.

Answer (score 3):

For some books, Google doens't have the copyright's holders permission to show the whole content of the book, so they just show a random subset of pages. Maybe, those permissions are also country-dependant, so they are allowed to show a different amount of pages depending on the country.

That's why, in some cases, you can see a "different" subset of the book, as they haven't identified you as the same user that already saw the book (you're using different browsers and or from different countries)